# How to hide/show a specific icon on Mac OS X Desktop

Tags: macos, terminal, icon

I have managed to write a piece of code in `.profile` file in bash to hide/show all the icons from the Desktop, running from Terminal.

I need the same functionality just for 1 icon to work with after I have hidden all in the first place.

So I need something like `showicon %1` command, where `%1` is the name of the icon on Desktop.

Any Suggestions on how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Terminal* command `chflags` can be used to hide and unhide files:

```
    chflags hidden /path/to/file.ext
```

or

```
    chflags nohidden /path/to/file.ext
```

You can create a simple alias called `hideicon` that invokes `chflags hidden`, and similarly for `showicon` to invoke the opposite command:

```
    alias hideicon='chflags hidden'
```

and

```
    alias showicon='chflags nohidden'
```

Add these to your `~/.bashrc` file, and they'll load with each new instance of your shell.